# Group values by unique elements

Tags: r

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
a <- c("A110","A110","A110","B220","B220","C330","D440","D440","D440","D440","D440","D440","E550")
```

I would like to create another another vector, based on a, that should look like:

```
b <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5)
```

In other words, b should assign a value (starting from 1) to each different element of a.

Comment: I changed it by mistake wanting to amend the original question. Open to suggestions to make it better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, (I assume) this is your vector

```
a <- c("A110","A110","A110","B220","B220","C330","D440","D440","D440","D440","D440","D440","E550")
```

As per possible solutions, here are few (can't find a good dupe right now)

```
as.integer(factor(a))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

Or

```
cumsum(!duplicated(a))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

Or

```
match(a, unique(a))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

Also `rle` will work the similarly in your *specific* scenario

```
with(rle(a), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

Or (which is practically the same)

```
data.table::rleid(a)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
```

---

Though be advised that all 4 solutions have their unique behavior in different scenarios, consider the following vector

```
a <- c("B110","B110","B110","A220","A220","C330","D440","D440","B110","B110","E550")
```

And the results of the 4 different solutions:

1.

```
as.integer(factor(a))
# [1] 2 2 2 1 1 3 4 4 2 2 5
```

The `factor` solution begins with `2` because `a` is unsorted and hence the first values are getting higher `integer` representation within the `factor` function. Hence, this solution is only valid *if your vector is sorted*, so don't use it other wise.

2.

```
cumsum(!duplicated(a))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5
```

This `cumsum/duplicated` solution got confused because of `"B110"` already been present at the beginning and hence grouped `"D440","D440","B110","B110"` into the same group.

3.

```
match(a, unique(a))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 1 1 5
```

This `match/unique` solution added ones at the end, because it is sensitive to `"B110"` showing up in more than one sequences (because of `unique`) and hence grouping them all into same group regardless of where they appear

4.

```
with(rle(a), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6
```

This solution only cares about sequences, hence different sequences of `"B110"` were grouped into different groups

Comment: My preference goes to `match`

Comment: @docendodiscimus they are behave differently in different situation though. I'm thinking to expand that answer to several scenarios

Comment: cumsum is more intuitive

Comment: Yeah, that might be valuable info

Comment: @docendodiscimus Added some scenarios