# How to assign incremental values based on two columns in R?

Tags: r

My data set looks like:

```
ID   VISIT_ID  DATE  DV
1001 112233    12-23 3
1001 112233    12-23 4
1001 112244    12-23 5
1001 112244    12-23 6
1001 112244    12-23 7
1001 112244    12-23 8
1002 112254    12-23 3
1002 112254    12-23 4
1002 112254    12-23 5
1002 112264    12-23 6
1002 112264    12-23 7
1002 112264    12-23 8
```

I want the results like below; it assign a incremental encounter value for each unique VISIT_ID. The sequence will restart from 1 for each ID. Helps will be much appreciated.

```
ID   VISIT_ID  DATE  DV  ENCOUNTER
1001 112233    12-23 3   1
1001 112233    12-23 4   1
1001 112244    12-23 5   2
1001 112244    12-23 6   2
1001 112244    12-23 7   2
1001 112244    12-23 8   2
1002 112254    12-23 3   1
1002 112254    12-23 4   1
1002 112254    12-23 5   1
1002 112264    12-23 6   2
1002 112264    12-23 7   2
1002 112264    12-23 8   2
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006427/group-values-by-unique-elements/37007036#37007036 in order to understand better the pros/cons of the below proposed solutions + some additional options.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` to find the index of unique 'VISIT_ID' after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(ENCOUNTER = match(VISIT_ID, unique(VISIT_ID))) 
#      ID VISIT_ID  DATE    DV ENCOUNTER
#    <int>    <int> <chr> <int>     <int>
#1   1001   112233 12-23     3         1
#2   1001   112233 12-23     4         1
#3   1001   112244 12-23     5         2
#4   1001   112244 12-23     6         2
#5   1001   112244 12-23     7         2
#6   1001   112244 12-23     8         2
#7   1002   112254 12-23     3         1
#8   1002   112254 12-23     4         1
#9   1002   112254 12-23     5         1
#10  1002   112264 12-23     6         2
#11  1002   112264 12-23     7         2
#12  1002   112264 12-23     8         2
```

---

Or another option is `duplicated`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(ENCOUNTER = cumsum(!duplicated(VISIT_ID)))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, ENCOUNTER := match(VISIT_ID, unique(VISIT_ID), by = ID]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
with(df1, ave(VISIT_ID, ID, FUN = function(x) cumsum(!duplicated(x))))
```

Comment: `ave(df$VISIT_ID, df$ID,FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

With `base R` `ave` we can convert the `VISIT_ID` to `factor` and then `numeric` to get unique number for every `VISIT_ID` of `ID`

```
df$ENCOUNTER <- ave(df$VISIT_ID, df$ID,FUN = function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
df

#     ID VISIT_ID  DATE DV ENCOUNTER
#1  1001   112233 12-23  3         1
#2  1001   112233 12-23  4         1
#3  1001   112244 12-23  5         2
#4  1001   112244 12-23  6         2
#5  1001   112244 12-23  7         2
#6  1001   112244 12-23  8         2
#7  1002   112254 12-23  3         1
#8  1002   112254 12-23  4         1
#9  1002   112254 12-23  5         1
#10 1002   112264 12-23  6         2
#11 1002   112264 12-23  7         2
#12 1002   112264 12-23  8         2
```

Comment: I would say this as problematic by the way you converted to `numeric`

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. In which case would it fail?

Comment: Suppose you have elements like `as.numeric(factor(c("B", "B", "A", "A")))` (though in the example showed, it could work)

Comment: Yep. In case if we have `VISIT_ID` as strings we can use the `match` or `cumsum` option.

Comment: Yes, but then it will be bordering on plagiarism... :-)

Comment: I can provide answers on data provided by OP. :-)